# Rails based blogging platform with template chooser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any particular gem which allows to create templates in a blogging platform for bloggers to choose from.

Basically how to integrate such a method in an ordinary blog app built from a basic tutorial like the from the Rails Guide itself.

Thank you

Comment: What am i supposed to look for. I am not being naive. I need to understand how such systems work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the gems I found by quick googling:

- [themes_for_rails](https://github.com/lucasefe/themes_for_rails)
- [web-app-theme](https://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme)
- [rails-theme-helper](https://github.com/tsechingho/rails-theme-helper)

Comment: ok thanks a lot. that would be a good start. but sir i am unable to grasp the concept of such a system

Comment: Do you have any specific questions? Just read the docs: https://github.com/lucasefe/themes_for_rails/wiki

Comment: what i am aiming for is a platform where users can select a theme and then have their own website. putting it plain and simple. since, as a newbie, starting a blog built as a platform should be a nice way to learn how such system works and further develop it, i was looking for some guides or ideas to understand how to begin and implement. the best i got when i searched for rails website builder, was this - [website_builder_engine](https://github.com/DanielKehoe/website_builder_engine). some what similar to a Saas platform